# How to resolve basic network error in volley

Tags: android, json, android-volley

**When i am trying to hit this function through wifi then is working fine but on mobile network i am getting this error ...D/Volley: [3641] BasicNetwork.logSlowRequests: HTTP response for request=<[ ] https://fruitnveggiemart.com/public/api/register 0x95bac5ee NORMAL 14>**

*
2020-07-30 16:16:54.671 24632-24863/com.fruitnveggiemart.ind E/Volley: [3640] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 409 for https://fruitnveggiemart.com/public/api/register
2020-07-30 16:16:54.678 24632-24632/com.fruitnveggiemart.ind I/TouchMotionHandler: handler onDetached
2020-07-30 16:16:54.703 24632-24632/com.fruitnveggiemart.ind V/Typeface: CurFontPath: /system/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf
2020-07-30 16:16:54.703 24632-24632/com.fruitnveggiemart.ind D/Typeface: switch to android orgin ttf
2020-07-30 16:16:54.711 24632-24632/com.fruitnveggiemart.ind W/System.err: com.android.volley.ClientError
2020-07-30 16:16:54.712 24632-24632/com.fruitnveggiemart.ind W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:199)
2020-07-30 16:16:54.712 24632-24632/com.fruitnveggiemart.ind W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:131)
2020-07-30 16:16:54.712 24632-24632/com.fruitnveggiemart.ind W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:111)
2020-07-30 16:16:54.712 24632-24632/com.fruitnveggiemart.ind W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:90)
2020-07-30 16:17:57.841 24632-24699/com.fruitnveggiemart.ind W/DpmTcmClient: read failed bytes countRead: -1
2020-07-30 16:17:57.996 24632-24699/com.fruitnveggiemart.ind W/DpmTcmClient: read failed bytes countRead: -1
2020-07-30 16:18:02.601 24632-24632/com.fruitnveggiemart.ind D/DecorView: onConfigurationChanged displayWindowDecor = false, mWindowMode = 1, pkg = com.fruitnveggiemart.ind
2020-07-30 16:18:02.602 24632-24632/com.fruitnveggiemart.ind I/DecorView: onConfigurationChanged mBackgroundPadding = Rect(32, 32 - 32, 32), mFramePadding = Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0), pkg = com.fruitnveggiemart.ind
2020-07-30 16:18:02.626 24632-24864/com.fruitnveggiemart.ind I/DpmTcmClient: RegisterTcmMonitor from: $Proxy0
2020-07-30 16:18:02.628 24632-24632/com.fruitnveggiemart.ind I/TouchMotionHandler: handler onAttached
2020-07-30 16:18:10.229 24632-24864/com.fruitnveggiemart.ind D/Volley: [3641] BasicNetwork.logSlowRequests: HTTP response for request=<[ ] https://fruitnveggiemart.com/public/api/register 0x95bac5ee NORMAL 14> [lifetime=7602], [size=53], [rc=200], [retryCount=0]
2020-07-30 16:18:10.248 24632-24632/com.fruitnveggiemart.ind I/TouchMotionHandler: handler onDetached
2020-07-30 16:18:10.272 24632-24632/com.fruitnveggiemart.ind V/Typeface: CurFontPath: /system/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf
2020-07-30 16:18:10.272 24632-24632/com.fruitnveggiemart.ind D/Typeface: switch to android orgin ttf
2020-07-30 16:18:10.334 24632-27305/com.fruitnveggiemart.ind V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 99252
2020-07-30 16:18:10.343 24632-27305/com.fruitnveggiemart.ind V/FA: Connecting to remote service
2020-07-30 16:18:10.344 24632-24632/com.fruitnveggiemart.ind W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@e551f8d
2020-07-30 16:18:10.359 24632-27305/com.fruitnveggiemart.ind V/FA: Activity paused, time: 84226696
2020-07-30 16:18:10.362 24632-27303/com.fruitnveggiemart.ind V/FA: onActivityCreated
2020-07-30 16:18:10.393 24632-24632/com.fruitnveggiemart.ind I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
2020-07-30 16:18:10.433 24632-27305/com.fruitnveggiemart.ind V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2020-07-30 16:18:10.475 24632-27305/com.fruitnveggiemart.ind V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 84226848
2020-07-30 16:18:10.492 24632-24632/com.fruitnveggiemart.ind I/TouchMotionHandler: handler onAttached
2020-07-30 16:18:10.549 24632-27305/com.fruitnveggiemart.ind V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2020-07-30 16:18:10.552 24632-27305/com.fruitnveggiemart.ind V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2020-07-30 16:18:10.697 24632-27305/com.fruitnveggiemart.ind D/FA: Connected to remote service
2020-07-30 16:18:10.699 24632-27305/com.fruitnveggiemart.ind V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
2020-07-30 16:18:11.015 24632-24632/com.fruitnveggiemart.ind I/TouchMotionHandler: handler onDetached
2020-07-30 16:18:12.061 24632-24632/com.fruitnveggiemart.ind V/Typeface: CurFontPath: /system/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf
2020-07-30 16:18:12.061 24632-24632/com.fruitnveggiemart.ind D/Typeface: switch to android orgin ttf
2020-07-30 16:18:15.743 24632-27305/com.fruitnveggiemart.ind V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
2020-07-30 16:18:15.745 24632-27305/com.fruitnveggiemart.ind W/ConnectionTracker: Exception thrown while unbinding
*

'''     public void registrationNetworkCall() {

```
    try {

        pDialog.setTitle("Registering..");
        pDialog.show();
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

        json.put("name", et_name.getText().toString());
        json.put("email", et_email.getText().toString());
        json.put("mobile_no", numberPHone);

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, Constants.BASE_URL + Constants.REGISTER_USER, json,
                response -> {

                    CommonMethod.hideDialog(pDialog);
                    try {
                        boolean success = response.getBoolean("success");
                        if (success) {
                            String message = response.optString("message");
                            String token = response.optString("successtoken");
                            int userId = response.optInt("user_id");
                            objCustomSharedPrefs.storeStringValueInPrefs(Keys.BASIC_AUTH, token);
                            objCustomSharedPrefs.storeIntValueInPrefs(Keys.MEMBER_ID, userId);
                            CommonMethod.showToast(mContext, message);

                            Intent intent = new Intent(UserProfileBackup.this, UserDashboard.class);
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();

                        } else {
                            String error = response.optString("error");
                            CommonMethod.showToast(mContext, error);
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse (VolleyError error){
                CommonMethod.hideDialog(pDialog);
                if (error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                    //This indicates that the reuest has either time out or there is no connection
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "nocnnecitno error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                    // Error indicating that there was an Authentication Failure while performing the request
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "AuthFailureError error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {



                    //Indicates that the server responded with a error response
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "ServerError error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                    //Indicates that there was network error while performing the request
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "NetworkError error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                    // Indicates that the server response could not be parsed
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "ParseError error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest, "OTPREQUESTING");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this will help you. Try this

```
                final JsonObjectRequest postRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                        new JSONObject(strJsonMapObject), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {


                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        CustomDiallog.StopLoading();

                        CustomDiallog.showVolleyError(activity.this, Error_log.handleVolleyError(error));
                    }
                }) {
                    @Override
                    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                        HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                        headers.put("User-agent", System.getProperty("http.agent"));

                        return headers;
                    }
                };
                GlobalVariables.volleyJsonObjectRequest(postRequest);
                AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(postRequest);
```

Call this method jest before add request object. Waits for 5 seconds

```
                public static void volleyJsonObjectRequest(JsonObjectRequest req) {
                    int socketTimeout = 5000;                                  // 5 seconds. You can change it
                    RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout,
                            2,
                            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
                    req.setRetryPolicy(policy);
                }
```